# What is the meaning of “$$$1” sign in Bootstrap.js file

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In the following JavaScript code there is a dollar sign “$$$1". What does it mean?

```js
var Util = function ($$$1) {...} //Line 62 bootstrap.js V4
$$$1(this).one(Util.TRANSITION_END, function () {
      called = true;
    }); //Line 103 bootstrap.js V4
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference to jQuery. If you see the definition of the function, it is something like this:

```
var Util = function ($$$1) {...}($);
```

Notice the `$` at the end. It means that the function expression is being called with a variable `$`, which refers to jQuery. Then throughout the function, jQuery is referred to as `$$$1`. So, a call like this:

```
$$$1(this).one(Util.TRANSITION_END ...
```

becomes like this:

```
$(this).one(Util.TRANSITION_END ...
```

which is a regular jQuery event binding.

Answer (score 0):

It's just another variable name, though a pretty opaque one, since it's not descriptive at all. If you search-replaced all `$$$1` with `someFunc`, the script would still work just as well.